# Custom Spatial Convolution In Torch

Tags: lua, neural-network, convolution, torch

I need to perform a custom spatial convolution in Torch. Rather than simply multiplying each input pixel by a weight for that pixel and adding them together with the filter's bias to form each output pixel, I need to do a more complex mathematical function to the input pixels before adding them together.

I know how to do this, but I do not know a GOOD way to do this. The best way I've come up with is to take the full input tensor, create a bunch of secondary tensors that are "views" of the original without allocating additional memory, putting those into a Replicate layer (the output filter count being the replication count), and feeding that into a ParallelTable layer containing a bunch of regular layers that have their parameters shared between filters.

The trouble is, even though this is fine memory-wise with a very manageable overhead, we're talking **inputwidth**^**inputheight**^**inputdepth**^**outputdepth** mini-networks, here. Maybe there's some way to create massive "long and tall" networks that work on the entire replicated input set at once, but how do I create layers that are partially-connected (like convolutions) instead of fully-connected?

I would have liked to just use inheritance to create a special copy of the regular **SpatialConvolution "class"** and modify it, but I can't even try because it's implemented in an external C library. I can't just use regular layers before a regular SpatialConvolution layer because I need to do my math with different weights and biases for each filter (shared between applications of the same filter to different input coordinates).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question. You made me give some serious thought.
Your approach has a flaw: it does not allow to take advantage of vectorized computations since each mini-network works independently.

**My idea is as follows:**

Suppose network's `input` and `output` are 2D tensors. We can produce (efficiently, without memory copying) an auxiliary 4D tensor 
`rf_input (kernel_size x kernel_size x output_h x output_w)` 
such that `rf_input[:, :, k, l]` is a 2D tensor of size `kernel_size x kernel_size` containing a receptive field which `output[k, l]` will be gotten from. Then we iterate over positions inside the kernel `rf_input[i, j, :, :]` getting pixels at position `(i, j)` inside all receptive fields and computing their contribution to each `output[k, l]` at once using vectorization.

**Example:**

Let our "convolving" function be, for example, a product of tangents of sums:

[image]

Then its partial derivative w.r.t. the `input` pixel at position `(s,t)` in its receptive field is

[image]

Derivative w.r.t. `weight` is the same.

At the end, of course, we must sum up gradients from different `output[k,l]` points. For example, each `input[m, n]` contributes to at most `kernel_size^2` outputs as a part of their receptive fields, and each `weight[i, j]` contributes to all `output_h x output_w` outputs.

**Simple implementation may look like this:**

```
require 'nn'
local CustomConv, parent = torch.class('nn.CustomConv', 'nn.Module')

-- This module takes and produces a 2D map. 
-- To work with multiple input/output feature maps and batches, 
-- you have to iterate over them or further vectorize computations inside the loops.

function CustomConv:__init(ker_size)
    parent.__init(self)

    self.ker_size = ker_size
    self.weight = torch.rand(self.ker_size, self.ker_size):add(-0.5)
    self.gradWeight = torch.Tensor(self.weight:size()):zero()
end

function CustomConv:_get_recfield_input(input)
    local rf_input = {}
    for i = 1, self.ker_size do
        rf_input[i] = {}
        for j = 1, self.ker_size do
            rf_input[i][j] = input[{{i, i - self.ker_size - 1}, {j, j - self.ker_size - 1}}]
        end
    end
    return rf_input
end

function CustomConv:updateOutput(_)
    local output = torch.Tensor(self.rf_input[1][1]:size())
    --  Kernel-specific: our kernel is multiplicative, so we start with ones
    output:fill(1)                                              
    --
    for i = 1, self.ker_size do
        for j = 1, self.ker_size do
            local ker_pt = self.rf_input[i][j]:clone()
            local w = self.weight[i][j]
            -- Kernel-specific
            output:cmul(ker_pt:add(w):tan())
            --
        end
    end
    return output
end

function CustomConv:updateGradInput_and_accGradParameters(_, gradOutput)
    local gradInput = torch.Tensor(self.input:size()):zero()
    for i = 1, self.ker_size do
        for j = 1, self.ker_size do
            local ker_pt = self.rf_input[i][j]:clone()
            local w = self.weight[i][j]
            -- Kernel-specific
            local subGradInput = torch.cmul(gradOutput, torch.cdiv(self.output, ker_pt:add(w):tan():cmul(ker_pt:add(w):cos():pow(2))))
            local subGradWeight = subGradInput
            --
            gradInput[{{i, i - self.ker_size - 1}, {j, j - self.ker_size - 1}}]:add(subGradInput)
            self.gradWeight[{i, j}] = self.gradWeight[{i, j}] + torch.sum(subGradWeight)
        end
    end
    return gradInput
end

function CustomConv:forward(input)
    self.input = input
    self.rf_input = self:_get_recfield_input(input)
    self.output = self:updateOutput(_)
    return self.output
end

function CustomConv:backward(input, gradOutput)
    gradInput = self:updateGradInput_and_accGradParameters(_, gradOutput)
    return gradInput
end
```

If you change this code a bit:

```
updateOutput:                                             
    output:fill(0)
    [...]
    output:add(ker_pt:mul(w))

updateGradInput_and_accGradParameters:
    local subGradInput = torch.mul(gradOutput, w)
    local subGradWeight = torch.cmul(gradOutput, ker_pt)
```

then it will work exactly as `nn.SpatialConvolutionMM` with zero `bias` (I've tested it).